# How to send image through ajax (axios with vue.js) to controller and how to access it afterwards?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

I've been trying to figure this thing out for some time now. 
What I'm trying to do is upload an image and then submit the form via ajax and access it in the controller.
The part of code where I POST data:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', files[0]);

axios.post('/uploadImg', {
      formData
   })
.then(response => console.log(response.data));
```

If I `console.log(formData.get('file'));` before the axios.post thing I see all the data I need:
[image]
 but when I try to access it inside the controller, like: `$request->file('file');` or `$request->file;` or even if I try to `return $request->all();` I get empty object? :
[image]
I'm pretty sure I'm doing the $request thing incorrectly or did I mess up things prior to that?
*By the way, I'm using vue.js to post ajax data and framework that I'm working on is laravel.*

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: use `dd($request->file('file')):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the reason I couldn't access those images were due to their size. I fixed it by changing some lines in php.ini. So I set: filememory_limit to 256M and upload_max_filesize to 10M. Now it all works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an options object and set the header:

```
    axios.post('/uploadImg', {
      formData
   }, {headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
```